# Insulating The House Windows for the NY (Long Island) Winter?

Tags: insulation, heating, winterizing, winter

I've experimented around with room insulation before using bubble wrap over the windows, which was marginally effective, approximately doubling the small R value of the windows, this year, I decided to try R6 rigid foam boards cut by table saw over the windows in my room.

The tolerances are very tight, and it is held against the window frame by a brick so that it does not move.[image: Insulation Picture]

Is this a good way to insulate windows against conduction/convection with intra-house air (the panels also have an IR reflective layer)? I have a few friends in Canada and Sweden that I've consulted with, who hang large sheets over their windows for insulation to decent effect.

Unfortunately, my house is heated with oil (I'm a fairly decent heat pump advocate) which has spiked in price this year due to geopolitical factors, so avoiding a large bill is essential to not significantly hurt my family's finances.

We plan on deploying rigid foam panels over some of the glass (the largest area regions) and using bubble wrap elsewhere.

Is this a good plan for thermal retention? Are there any improvements that could be made to it to make it more efficient?

House foyer:
[image: Foyer]

**Misc:**
We're also going to be employing a number of different strategies to minimize oil use such as strategic use of lower thermostat temperatures in the main areas, shifting the heating burden to the room insulation, space heaters, and electronics (computers) in the room to maintain ~20C-23C.

Comment: Windows usually are where there are drafts/air leaks.  The window insulation kits for sale are helpful for cutting down on drafts(and keep seeing out windows).

Comment: Since putting solid insulation panels over the windows completely blocks their usefulness as windows, why not just remove the windows completely, fill the space with insulation, and side over the outside/drywall the inside. That will give you far better R-value than anything you can add to the inside, and you'll be using artificial light all winter long anyway, may as well continue through the summer, too.

Comment: I think removing all the windows in the house might be a bit extreme...

The summers can be trivially managed with single-directional IR/UV reflecting films. @FreeMan

Comment: Have you considered air sealing the house as well? Sometimes there are easy fixes available for air leakage, and it can make a big difference in comfort. Fewer drafts also means you can run a lower thermostat temperature in most cases.

Comment: I'll look into it for sure!